# In search bar data Is showing in drop-down after selecting particular data is not binding all the data is binding how we can resolve it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**It is my html code**
`''''

```
 <div class="widget-content">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>AltText</label>
                                <input type="hidden" id="alttextTestscardadsId" value="" />
                                <input type="text" id="altText" action-type="typeahead-altText" class="form-control" placeholder="[Any]" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                                <div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doFilter();">Filter</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="doClear();">Clear</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                     </div> 
              </div>
```

`
**It is my controller.js**

```
$scope.loadRecordSet = function (tableState) {
        debugger;
        tableState.alttextFilterTestscardadsId = angular.element("#alttextTestscardadsId").val() ? angular.element("#alttextTestscardadsId").val() : 0;
        tableState.pagination.number = $scope.pageSize;
        $scope.currentPageSize = parseInt($scope.pageSize);
        //refresh current state
        currentState = tableState;

        //show loader 
        common.showLoader(".widget-content");
        //get record set
        testscardadsSvc.getCardAds(tableState)
            .then(function (res) {
                debugger;
                common.hideLoader(".widget-content");
                $scope.recordSet = res.data;
               
                var totalRecords = res.data[0].totalRecords;
                tableState.pagination.pageSize = $scope.pageSize;
                tableState.pagination.numberOfPages = common.getNumberOfPages(totalRecords, $scope.pageSize);
                tableState.pagination.totalItemCount = totalRecords;
                $scope.isRecordSetLoaded = true;
                $scope.currentPageNumber = (tableState.pagination.start + $scope.currentPageSize) / $scope.currentPageSize;
            },
                function () {
                    common.hideLoader(".widget-content");
                    common.processErrorResponse(res);
                }
            );
    }
```

**And this is my js file for only search bar**

```
this.initiateTestsCardAdsFilterAutoCompleter = function () {
        debugger
        $('input[type=text][action-type=typeahead-altText]').typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {
                var $items = [""];
                $.post(common.mapUrl("testscardads", "GetTestsCardAdsByAltText"), { "filterKey": query, "limit": 15 }, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.length != 0) {
                        $.map(data, function (item) {
                            var group = {
                                id: item.value,
                                name: item.text
                            };
                            $items.push(group);
                        });
                        process($items);
                    } else {
                        $('input[type=text][action-type=]').typeahead('hide');
                    }
                });
            },
            items: 15,
            minLength: 1,
            highlight: true,
            updater: function (selectedItem) {
                $("#alttextTestscardadsId").val(selectedItem.id);
                return selectedItem.name; typeahead - altText
            }
        });
    };
};
```

**And My Controller**

```
   [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Manage()
        {
            var totalBidAmount = _repository.Entity().Sum(x => x.BidAmount).ToString();
            ViewBag.TotalBidAmount = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(totalBidAmount) ? totalBidAmount : "0";
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Manage([FromBody] CardAdsTableState tableState)
        {
            try
            {
                if (tableState != null)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableState.Sort.Predicate))
                    {
                        tableState.Sort.Predicate = "CreatedOn";
                        tableState.Sort.Reverse = false;
                    }

                    //get page number
                    var pageNo = tableState.Pagination.Start / tableState.Pagination.Number;

                    //get records 
                    return Ok(await _testscardAdsModel.Filter(tableState.FilterKey, tableState.Sort.Predicate, tableState.Sort.Direction, pageNo, null, tableState.Pagination.Number, tableState));
                }
                else
                {
                    Utility.WriteLog($"ManageCardAds Message: CardAdsTableState value will be null");
                    Utility.WriteLog($"ManageCardAds Inner Exception: CardAdsTableState value will be null");
                    return Ok(null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utility.WriteLog($"ManageCardAds Message: {ex.Message}");
                Utility.WriteLog($"ManageCardAds Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException.Message}");

                await _errorLogManager.ErrorLog(HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>());

                return Ok(null);
            }
        }
        

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetTestsCardAdsByAltText(string filterKey, int limit = 10)
        {
            return Json(_testscardAdsModel.GetTestsCardAdsByAltText(filterKey, limit).Select(x => new { text = x.AltText.ToString(), value = x.Id}));
        }

    }
}
```

**It is my interface**

```
  public interface ITestsCardAdsModel
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<TestsCardAdsDetailViewModel>> Filter(string sortBy, string sortDir, string predicate, int pageNo, string name, int pageSize, CardAdsTableState tableState);

        List<CardAd> GetTestsCardAdsByAltText(string query, int limit = 10);

        
    }
```

**And Its my model**

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<TestsCardAdsDetailViewModel>> Filter(string sortBy, string sortDir, string direction, int pageNo, string name, int pageSize, CardAdsTableState tablestate)
        {
            try
            {
                var model = _repository.Entity().Include(x => x.CardAdLandingPage).Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToList();
                // && tablestate.AltText == x.AltText).ToList();

                //var tablestateIdList = 0;
                //if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tablestate.AltText))
                //{
                //    tablestateIdList =Convert.ToInt32(tablestate.AltText);
                //}

                var testscardAdsDetailViewModelList = new List<TestsCardAdsDetailViewModel>();
                    foreach (var cardAdModel in model)
                    {
                        var testscardAdsDetailViewModel = new TestsCardAdsDetailViewModel();
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.Id = cardAdModel.Id;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.AltText = cardAdModel.AltText;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.AdCopy = cardAdModel.AdCopy;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.BidAmount = cardAdModel.BidAmount;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.EmailAlertRecipient = cardAdModel.CardAdLandingPage.EmailAlertRecipient.Replace(",", "\n");
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.IsShowLive = cardAdModel.IsShowLive;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.Status = cardAdModel.Status ? "Enabled" : "Disabled";
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.CreatedOn = cardAdModel.CreatedOn;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.CompanyName = cardAdModel.CompanyId != null
                                                                      ? _companyRepository.Entity().Where(x => x.Id == cardAdModel.CompanyId).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault()
                                                                     : null;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.ContactId = cardAdModel.CardAdLandingPage.ContactId;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.CompanyId = cardAdModel.CompanyId;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.SubmissionCount = cardAdModel.CardAdLandingPage.CardAdSubmissionCount;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.ClickCount = cardAdModel.CardAdLandingPage.CardAdClickCount;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModel.ContactName = cardAdModel.CardAdLandingPage.ContactName;
                        testscardAdsDetailViewModelList.Add(testscardAdsDetailViewModel);
                    }
                
                    return testscardAdsDetailViewModelList;
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utility.WriteLog($"GetCardAds Message: {ex.Message}");
                Utility.WriteLog($"GetCardAds Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException.Message}");

                var errorLog = new ErrorLog
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Source = ex.Source.ToString(),
                    Message = ex.Message,
                    StackTrace = ex.ToString(),
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
                };
                await _errorLogManager.ErrorLog(errorLog);

                return null;
            }
        }

        public List<CardAd> GetTestsCardAdsByAltText(string query, int limit = 10)
        {
            var resultSet = _repository.Filter(x => x.AltText
                            .ToLower()
                            .Contains(query.ToLower()))
                            .OrderBy(x => x.AltText)
                            .Take(limit).ToList();

            return resultSet;
        }
```

And the code is running smoothly there are no any errors and the data is also binding properly.
And I have added search box after that whatever we checked that letter data is showing in the dropdown but after clicking filter it is binding all the table data. But I have selected in the search bar only one name according to that it want to show only one name
What is the error I think in model only the issue is their I have tried but it is not working I have tried that code I have commented in the upside.